# How to get the initial capacity of a Java data structure from the Class File

Tags: java, data-structures, bytecode, javassist

I wanna analyze the bytecode of a java program and gather some data including what fields are in there. So far, I was able to gather all the data about fields except the initial capacities of the declared data structured.

Is there any way to know the initial capacity of a declared data structure field by reading the bytecode? Or else, is there any other way to achieve the same task?

For example:
If I declare it like this `Map map = new HashMap(18);`, the initial capacity would be `18`. Like that!

I have used Javassist library so far and can I use it for this as well?

**The reason is I wanna analyze Java programs that use Java data structures inside and gather data about how those data structures have been initialized(initial capacity) and furthermore, how those data structures have grown after executing the program(according to the growing policy of Java data structures). Then my intention is to analyze the performance of those particular programs.**

Any answer would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "initial capacity"? I suspect that the information that you are looking for is hidden in executable code and not easily extracted from a class file. Also, this *might* be a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info), so if you could tell us *why* you want that specific piece of information, we might be able to suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: If I declare it like this `Map map = new HashMap(18);`, the initial capacity would be 18. Like that!

Comment: Thank you for commenting @JoachimSauer. My intention is to analyze Java programs that use Java data structures like `HashMap` and gather information about how those data structures have been initialized like initial capacity and growing policy etc. Is that possible to collect those data by analyzing the Class File or are there any alternative ways?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to manually look in the specification (or even code) of the relevant classes and store the resulting numbers in your code. In other words: pick a set of classes that you want to support and manually inspect them to find the relevant values (for a given JDK/library version, that is). I think that any fully-automated way to find that values will be a.) quite complex and b.) quite error-prone.

Comment: When `Map map = new HashMap(18);` is a field declaration, the `map = new HashMap(18);` assignment will be copied to every constructor that doesn’t delegate to another constructor. In other words, its bytecode is indistinguishable from having an individual `map = new HashMap(18);` in every constructor. But what if one constructor has `map = new HashMap(18);` and the other `map = new HashMap(24);`? The bytecode differs by only one byte from the variant with the `Map map = new HashMap(18);` field declaration, but you have to perform a deep analysis to find out.

Comment: Thanks for replying! What if I get the memory taken by each instance? For example, if I use something like `RamUsageEstimator` from `com.carrotsearch.sizeof.RamUsageEstimator` and get the memory size taken by the particular data structure! Can I consider something like the capacity is proportional to the memory usage? So then I can get the growing rate of the particular data structure as well right?

Comment: For example; I ran this code with an `ArrayList` of an initial size of 4. I added 5 elements to the list using a loop. According to the growing policy of the Java `ArrayList`, it should grow itself by 50%, which means after the 4rth element when I enter the 5th element new size would be 6. I got the following results,
`Bytes -> 72, 88, 104, 120, 144`. 
We can clearly see here that between the first 4 elements, the byte gap is 16, and eventually, at the 5th element, it has become 24. So, it clearly shows the growth and the rate right?

Comment: Sounds like you actually want to instrument the collection classes, to find out when they are created with what initial capacity and track how they grow.